# How can I use wifi to wirelessly communicate (and wirelessly code if possible) between multiple arduinos?

Tags: wifi, communication, wireless

I am using arduino as the base for an accelerometer project - the end goal is to have multiple arduinos with accelerometer chips that can wirelessly start and stop collecting data and wirelessly send this data back to the "base" arduino (which will be connected to a computer).  Currently we have only two arduinos communicating to test a lot of this, and currently are using a bluetooth node to wirelessly code the accelerometer arduino and Rf nodes to wirelessly send the data back to the arduino connected to a computer which then prints the data it is collecting.  How could we replace this with a wifi network?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun and https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Answer (score 1):

Sending data to a computer using WiFi is simple enough and there are plenty of examples. The simplest way is to set up a web server on the computer and use HTTP POST to send the data. There are "lighter" ways but entail more coding.

You won't do OTA updates on a normal Arduino. Yes, you could use a Yún, but they aren't always the best choice - the Linux side of things does make it a very "heavyweight* board.

You may be better off using an ESP8266 based system (not wired to an Arduino, but standalone) and programming it direct. Maybe a NodeMCU or something similar.  [The Arduino core for ESP8266 supports OTA programming direct from the Arduino IDE.](http://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/ota_updates/ota_updates.html)